# Why not simply use sine weights with Clenshaw-Curtis nodes?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature is based on writing
 $$
\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\cos y)\sin y dy
$$
and then replacing $f(\cos y)$ by a truncated Fourier series, so that the integral can be written as sum over these Fourier coefficients.

Why is it necessary to compute that Fourier series? Why can one not simply apply the trapezoidal rule to $f(\cos y)\sin y$? As far as I understand this should yield a quadrature rule with the same convergence rates (due to Euler-McLaurin) and same quadrature nodes but easier (numerically and conceptually) quadrature weights than Clenshaw-Curtis. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/include/boost/math/special_functions/chebyshev_transform.hpp

Comment: That one doesn't compute the Fourier series. If applies a type-II DCT to the function evaluated at Chebyshev nodes, which approximates the trapezoidal quadrature your speak of.

Comment: That procedure produces a Chebyshev series which is integrated,

Comment: @user14717 It approximates the trapezoidal rule? So it is not equal to what I'm proposing? Do you agree with my analysis?

Comment: Usually one uses DCT instead of FFT to obtain only a small number of coefficients that are not (almost) equal to zero. I'm not sure whether the quadrature weights would be better using trapezoidal rule in this case.

Comment: @thewavelad I don't believe it would be better, I believe it would be equally good and be easier, as neither FFT nor DCT would be needed

Comment: @Bananach: It is a trapezoidal rule in the rescaled space. The Chebyshev integration in Boost I referenced is more of a bonus, since the real goal of computing the Chebyshev transform is to get a stable interpolation and stable numerical differentiation scheme. So at least in that case, there isn't cause to do that Clenshaw-Curtis integration by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clenshaw-Curtis is interpolatory but the trapezoidal rule for the transformed function is not. Thus for $f(x)=1$ Clenshaw-Curtis will always spit out
$$\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx\approx2$$
But trapezoidal rule applied to the transformed function will result in
$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx&=\int_0^{\pi}1\cdot\sin\theta d\theta\\
&\approx\frac{\pi}{2N}\left[\sin(0)+2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sin\frac{k\pi}N+\sin(\pi)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}N\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{-1}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{2N}}\left(\cos\frac{\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi}N-\cos\frac{\left(k-\frac12\right)\pi}N\right)\\
&=\frac{-\pi}{2N\sin\frac{\pi}{2N}}\left(\cos\frac{\left(N-\frac12\right)\pi}N-\cos\frac{\pi}{2N}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}N\cot\frac{\pi}{2N}\approx2\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12N^2}\right)\end{align}$$
For a large number of subintervals $N$. Thus Clenshaw-Curtis is generally considered to use the functional values at the same points as the proposed method more efficiently.

Comment: Shouldn't the error of the rule I proposed convergence exponentially fast?

Comment: No, this is the same form for the error as the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis), $O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right)$ but it happens for a constant function already, no need to input a quadratic function to see some error.

Comment: I'm sorry,  I meant to apply the trapezoidal rule to a periodic function, for which the trapezoidal rule is indeed exponential (this is also the transformation that Clenshaw-Curtis is based on). I edited the question accordingly

Comment: With your latest edit we have $$\int_{-1}^11\cdot dx\approx\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}1\cdot\sin\theta\,d\theta=0$$ Probably you will want to revise this approach.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I think that answers my question. There is no proper way to do what I thought one can do. I'm sorry if I was unclear or still am but your answer together with this observation now really helped

Comment: For readers of this comment exchange: I put the question back in the original form

Comment: Although I've been a Negative Nancy and in general urinated on your parade in this thread, it seems that there really is a thing called [double exponential quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature) which amounts to transforming the variable of integration and then applying the trapezoidal rule to the transformed integral. So it's possible that your intuition on this question is better than mine and you just didn't hit on the right initial transformation.